# Get mod date to attach a version number to JS src script

Tags: php

Instead of the browser checking if the file was modified before serving the JS script (adds a few seconds to ping the server), or waiting for an arbitrary amount of time until the JS script expires, I have the PHP script instead attach a version number (e.g. `script.js?v=123`) to the JS script based off of the last modification date.

```
/**
 * Creates a new version once the file has been modified ensuring the user always receives the most updated file while still utilizing the browser cache
 *
 * @param $path string|array root: "/js/master/example.js" | local: "script.js"
 *
 * @return string
 */
function js($path){
    if(!empty($path)){
        if(is_array($path)){
            $return = '';
            foreach($path as $value){
                $return .= js($value);
            }
            return $return;
        } else {
            if (substr($path, 0, 1) <> '/') {
                $version = dechex(filemtime(getcwd().'/'.$path));
            } else {
                $version = dechex(filemtime(__DIR__.$path));
            }
            return "<script src='$path?v=$version'></script>\r\n";
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### API

The documentation says the function returns a string, yet the last line of the implementation says otherwise...

> ```
> /**
>  * ...
>  *
>  * @return string
>  */
> function js($path){
>     ...
>     return false;
> }
> ```

#### Replace a loop with `array_map`

Instead of this:

> ```
> $return = '';
> foreach($path as $value){
>     $return .= js($value);
> }
> return $return;
> ```

You can write a bit simpler using `array_map` and `join`:

```
if (is_array($path)) {
    return join('', array_map('js', $path));
}
```

#### Getting the first character from a string

Instead of `substr($path, 0, 1)`, when you know that `$path` is not empty (as in the posted code), a more natural way is to use indexing: `$path[0]`.

#### Don't repeat yourself

`dechex(filemtime(...))` is common in the two branches of this conditional:

> ```
> if (substr($path, 0, 1) <> '/') {
>     $version = dechex(filemtime(getcwd().'/'.$path));
> } else {
>     $version = dechex(filemtime(__DIR__.$path));
> }
> ```

Extract the common part:

```
if ($path[0] <> '/') {
    $dir = getcwd().'/';
} else {
    $dir = __DIR__;
}
```

#### Use early returns

Instead of this kind of code:

> ```
> if (cond1) {
>     if (cond2) {
>         // ...
>         return X;
>     } else {
>         // ...
>         return Y;
>     }
> }
> return Z;
> ```

You can use "early returns" to reduce the nesting,
and thereby making the code slightly easier to read:

```
if (!cond1) {
    return Z;
}

if (cond2) {
    // ...
    return X;
}

return Y;
```

#### Alternative implementation

Putting the above tips together:

```
function js($path) {
    if (empty($path)) {
        return '';
    }

    if (is_array($path)) {
        return join('', array_map('js', $path));
    }

    $dir = $path[0] <> '/' ? getcwd().'/' : __DIR__;
    $version = dechex(filemtime($dir.$path));
    return "<script src='$path?v=$version'></script>\r\n";
}
```

Comment: +1 Good solution to rewriting code, especially around de-nesting.  one could argue that the lone `else` condition in this code could also be designed out.

Comment: @MikeBrant Not sure if you were referring to replacing the small if-else with a ternary. In any case, I went for it ;-)

Comment: I was n't particularly  (as peopls have different opinions on that.  Was thinking more `$dir  = etcwd() . '/'; if ($path[0] === '/') { $dir = __DIR__; }` but eitehr way seems an improvement.

Comment: Beautiful solution. I'm getting a `Use of undefined constant js - assumed 'js'` notice. Should `js` in the array_map function be inside quotes?

Comment: @JaredDunham you're right, indeed it should be quoted. It was naive of me to presume that it's possible to refer to functions like that in PHP =)

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly one approach to take to get into cache busting, but it has a few problems:

- You are making a file-system access every single time you call this function.
- It couples your logic to an actual file deployment/touch event.  What if you need to redeploy your asset but it hasn't changed?  What if you are running in some sort of load balanced environment where file modification times on different servers might be out of sync with each other?  Do you now need to introduce "sticky" sessions to make sure the browser is utilizing its cache effectively?

If you have gotten to the point where you are beginning to really think about how to best optimize browser caching behavior, you are probably at the point where you should be thinking about revision controlling the assets themselves.  Why introduce an artificial cache-buster, when you yourself can give each version of javascript a different version name when you are packaging it for deployment?  You can then also have much finer-grained control in your application around which asset version you want to point to.  For example, say you have a configuration in your app to determine the javascript dependency (version number) you want to point to.  You could vary this configuration across your pre-prod and prod environments such that you can point them toward fully independent artifact versions.  Your cache busting needs go away (in favor of very long TTL's for each release of your javascript file) and your application is easier to test in different environments.   This also allows for easy decoupling of javascript asset deployment and deployment of applications consuming that dependency.

As far as your code, I think @janos did an excellent job with that and I would agree with his comments.